# Is it possible to disable the 'shift+space' shortcut in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

When I am editting data in the "edit top 200 rows" tab, I frequently press 'shift+space' as I am entering capitalized data, which kicks me out of edit mode. This is extremely annoying, and reduces my typing speed to around ~10% of normal. Is there any way to disable this shortcut in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope. This bug was closed as "won't fix" about two years ago (not enough people cared, I guess - only one person voted aside from me):

[http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=473303](https://web.archive.org/web/20090727003648/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=473303)

Of course my suggestion is to use UPDATE statements rather than the quirky Edit Top n grid, which has several other problems in addition to this one.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I saw that bug report, but I was hoping that it was merely a problem with the default keyboard shortcuts, rather than an inability to change keyboard shortcuts. 90% of the time I use `UPDATE` statements, but there are occasional times when I find it more convenient to work with the `Edit Top n` grid.

Comment: As long as you're aware of some of the other problems (ever try updating BIT columns, for example?).